# How to tell the age of an Android repeating alarm?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a `setRepeating()` alarm scheduled that I want to disable in it's `BroadcastReceiver` if it is of a certain age.  I would rather disable it inside of the `BroadcastReceiver`, so if its possible that would be my first choice.

In my `Activity`:

```
// Start our alarm
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Receiver.class);

long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
firstTime += 2 * 1000; // start in 2 seconds
long interval = 2000; // 2 seconds for testing

intent.putExtra("start", firstTime); // Tell the receiver the creation date (not working)

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, intent, 0);

// Schedule the alarm!
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, interval, sender);
```

In my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // ... alarm stuff
    long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    Log.i("", "Alarm Running for " + (now - intent.getLongExtra("start", now)));
    //getLongExtra() defaults to 'now' because there is no extra 'start'
}
```

In LogCat I see this..

```
08-19 11:01:04.420: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
08-19 11:01:06.420: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
08-19 11:01:08.430: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
08-19 11:01:10.420: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
08-19 11:01:12.419: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
08-19 11:01:14.419: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
08-19 11:01:16.420: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
08-19 11:01:18.420: INFO/(1371): Alarm Running for 0
```

Now this to me means that the intent does not contain the "start" extra that I gave it with `putExtra()`.

How do I tell the age of an alarm, either by intent extras or other methods?

Edit: I can find out how many times the Receiving class has received the broadcast by creating a `static int` and incrementing it every time the alarm code executes, but this is not a good way to find the "age".

Update: In combination from the answer provided by Mobius, you must also pass `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, like follows:

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a Bundle?

inside onReceive()

```
Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (myBundle != null) {
        long startTime = myBundle.get("start");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the second argument in the onReceive() method is the intent from Activity. Its the AlarmManager who's firing up the receiver, not your activity. If i'm right, my mind has only one solution for your problem - file stored externally, containing your alarm's start time.

It goes like this:

1. `Activity`:

   ```
   // Remember about adding
   // <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   // in your manifest xml
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourAppsName",
           ".alarmStartTime");
   try {
       BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), true));
       out.write(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
       out.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```
2. `BroadcastReceiver`:

   ```
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourAppsName",
           "alarmStartTime.txt");
   String content = "";
   try {
       content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   Log.i("", "Alarm Running for " + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - Long.decode(content)));
   ```

Although, its a cpu and battery killer if you'd run it every 2 seconds;)

Tell me again why can't you use this static variable? If you have specific interval between alarms, number of iterations can simply inform you about life span of the receiver.

Comment: I can, and since this is only for testing purposes it really doesn't matter how I implement it;) I simply asked the question out of curiosity and at this time I have no need to implement a solution other than the static var.. this is not generally an acceptable solution because of 'overkill' but +1 for viable solution